# How to get predicted column in R

Tags: r, naivebayes

i am working on a machine learning model in R using naive bayes package.

Following are the model framing' readFromCsv contains multiples of rows and columns with valid values.

```
model <- naiveBayes(student~ ., data = studentDataSet)
```

I do the prediction, and that gives me one of the classes as the prediction.

```
predict(model, studentDataSet[1:10,], type = "class")
```

but, what i am trying to achieve is to get the entire column details from predicted class, say, class,student,marks, grade etc., is list of rows in dataset,  i want to get all the values from predicted column.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether you understood the mechanism of a classification, but you could simply merge your prediction results and the data with `rbind(predictions, studentDataSet[1:10,]`

Answer (score 0):

If studentDataSet_test is your dataframe over which you want to predict, then:

```
studentDataSet_test$prediction <- predict(model, studentDataSet_test, type = "class")
print(studentDataSet_test)
# This will print all details with the prediction
```